# Sum of Bimodal Distributions?

Tags: sum, bimodal

If I'm trying to estimate a the sum of a bunch of random variables, where each random variable is a bimodal distribution, how would i go about thinking or modeling what that looks like?

Comment: A bit more context would be really useful. Can you say anything about these distributions other than bimodal? Do you have a particular application or problem in mind?